# What is the meaning of discriminator-value in Hibernate mapping file?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, discriminator

```
<class name="admin.model.OrganizationUnit" table="ORGANIZATION_UNIT" discriminator-value="admin.model.OrganizationUnit" dynamic-update="true">

    <id name="ObjectId" type="string" column="object_id">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="discriminator"/>
    <property name="ObjectType" type="string">
        <column name="ObjectType" sql-type="varchar2(255)" not-null="true"/>
    </property>

    <subclass name="admin.model.DmSystem" discriminator-value="admin.model.DmSystem" dynamic-update="true">

        <set name="ChildOrgs" lazy="true" table="ORGANIZATION_UNIT" where="ou_type_code='CWORG'">
            <key column="system_org_id"/>
            <one-to-many class="Dm.bizcomponent.admin.model.OrganizationUnit"/>
        </set>

        <set name="SystemAdminAccessGroup" lazy="true" inverse="true" table="CWGROUP" where="group_type_code='SYSTEM_ADMINACCESS'">
            <key column="owner_id"/>
            <one-to-many class="admin.model.Group"/>
        </set>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

> Here is the mapping code
>   In the above code there is one parent Class OrganizationUnit with two subclass

Answer (score 2):

The [discriminator-value](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass-discriminator) is used to determine the class type of the entity subclass type associated with a given database row entry in the base class database table.